# A strenghtening of FTC Requiring Only Approximate Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-integral

I am reading a small [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319494?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which seeks to construct a functions on $[0, 1]$ which is a derivative, yet it is not Riemann integrable. The paper has the following line:

"That $f$ is a derivative follows from the fact that it is bounded and approximately continuous so that it is the derivative of its indefinite Lebesgue integral $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt.$"

**Please Note:** The definition of approximate continuity is given at the bottom of this post.

I only studied Lebesgue measure and integration, I have never seen the differentiation stuff. I imagine there must be a theorem of the form:

**Theorem:** Suppose $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ in integrable, and $f$ is approximately continuous at $x_0 \in [a, b].$ Then $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiabl at $x_0$ with $F'(x_0) = f(x_0).$

However, I have not been able to find this theorem anywhere on the internet or in my books. Is there a reference to it somewhere, or is there a way to derive this theorem from other more common theorems? Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** The definitions of Lenesgue density, approximate continuity, and approximate limits, taken from the Encyclopedia of Mathematics (supported by Springer).

**Density of a Set:** https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Density_of_a_set

Given a Lebesgue measurable set $E$ in the standard Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the upper and lower densities of $E$ at $x$ are defined respectively as

$$\lim \sup_{r \to 0^+} \dfrac {m(E \cap B_r(x))}{w_n r^n} \quad \text{and} \quad \lim \inf_{r \to 0^+} \dfrac {m(E \cap B_r(x))}{w_nr^n}$$

where $w_n$ denotes the volume of the unit $n$-dimensional ball. If the two numbers coincides, i.e. if the following limit exists,

$$\lim_{r \to 0^+} \dfrac {m(E \cap B_r(x))}{w_n r^n}$$

the resulting number is called the density of $E$ at $x.$

**Approximate Limits:** https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Approximate_limit

Consider a (Lebesgue)-measurable set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, a measurable function $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ and a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where E has Lebesgue density $1$. The approximate upper and lower limits of $f$ at $x_0$ are defined, respectively, as

- The infimum of $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty \}$ such that the set ${f \le a}$ has density $1$ at $x_0$;
- The supremum of $a \in \{- \infty \} \cup \mathbb{R}$ such that the set $\{f \ge a \}$ has density $1$ at $x_0.$

They are usually denoted by

$$\text{ap} \lim \sup_{x \to x_0}f(x) \quad \quad \text{ and } \quad \quad \text{ap} \lim \inf_{x \to x_0}f(x)$$

If the two numbers coincide, then the result is called *the approximate limit at $x_0$* and is denoted by

$$\text{ap} \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$$

**Approximate Continuity:** 
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Approximate_continuity

Consider a (Lebesgue) measurable set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n,$ a measurable function $f:E \to \mathbb{R}^k$ and a point $x_0  \in E$ where the Lebesgue density of $E$ is $1$. $f$ is approximately continuous at $x_0$ if and only if the approximate limit of $f$ at $x_0$ exists and equals $f(x_0).$

Comment: It seems likely someone could give a proof of the theorem if you tell us what "approximately continuous" means...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I wasn't sure if that was a well-known definition or not. I am currently editing the post to include the definition.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have included the definitions in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to add a hypothesis:

> > **Theorem:** Suppose $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and bounded, and $f$ is approximately continuous at $x_0 \in [a, b].$ Then $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiabl at $x_0$ with $F'(x_0) = f(x_0).$

Proof: Wlog $x_0=0$ and $f(0)=0$. An elementary result in one of the links in the question shows that there exists a set $E$ with $$\lim_{E\ni x\to 0}f(x)=0$$ and such that $E$ has density $1$ at $0$. Write $$f=f_1+f_2,$$ $$f_1=f\chi_E.$$Let $F_j(x)=\int_0^x f_j$. Then $f_1$ is continuous at $0$, hence $$F_1'(0)=0.$$And, assuming $h>0$ so the notation makes sense,  $$\frac{|F_2(h)-F_2(0)|}{h}\le ||f||_\infty\frac{m((0,h)\setminus E)}{h},$$which shows $F_2'(0)=0$, since $E$ has density $1$ at $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! And just to make sure, there are no shenanigans with the definition of derivative in the Lebesgue setting, right? The derivative of $f$ at $x$ is still $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, right?

Comment: @Ovi Right.....